# Deploy lambda function inline

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a python function that I can deploy through S3 bucket. But it is possible to deploy a function "inline"...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html

But I do not see any clear instructions about how to do this. I do not want to use S3 bucket.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can deploy an AWS Lambda function inline within a CloudFormation template through the following YAML syntax.

```
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: >
          def handler(event, context):
            print('hello from lambda')
      Handler: index.handler
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ LambdaRole , "Arn" ]
      Runtime: python3.6
      Timeout: 60
```

Comment: Just for the sake of reference, Can you point to the documentation of Code: ZipFile > section?

Comment: The documentation you already linked states, that the Zipfile property allows for inline code. The rest is basically YAML syntax (and a lot of trial and error).

Comment: @shantanuo Here is AWS example with inline code https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html#cfn-lambda-function-code-zipfile

Comment: I am wondering why you have used `>` insead of a pipe `|` ?

Answer (score -1):

- When you create a lambda function you will see option to choose language.
- Choose python
- Create function
- As soon as function is created you will see edit inline option and a file of your lambda_function_name/lambda_function.py with code

  ```
  import json.
  def lambda_handler(event, context):
  return {
   'statusCode': 200,
   'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
  }
  ```

you can edit this based upon requirement.This is inline.